# How to add a button under an image with google maps?

Tags: html

I'm new to HTML. I have a table and a map canvas (Google Maps API) side by side. I'm trying to add a button under the map canvas to set the zoom/center of the map to default. Problem is I don't know the correct syntax to position it.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <table border="1", id="myTable", cellpadding="10", style="float:left">
        <tr>
          <th>Name of Business</th>
          <th>Latitude</th>
          <th>Longitude</th>
          <th>Center Map</th>
        </tr>
        </table>

        <div id="map_canvas" style="float:right;width:1024px;height:600px;border:black">

        </div>

        <button onclick="map.setCenter(myOptions.center), map.setZoom(9)", style="float:bottom">Recenter Map</button>
    </div>
</body>
```

Right now the "Recenter Map" button is at the top and in between the table and map canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is **not** related to google maps api.

its basic html.

you should've tried google first.

anyway, add a `<br>` break after the `div`.

---

ok, since you're knew, lets do a quick analysis of your code.

- Do not separate attributes with a comma. (`<table border="1", id="myTable",`)
- Do not use inline styles. (`style="float:left"`)
- To have 2 divs side by side you should set `display: inline-block`.
- If you create another div you can put your button in, and it will be under the other divs. Or just make sure your button is after the last `</div>` in your code.

Comment: @cYn: ok. i removed the tag.

Comment: Did you mean <br> between <div>map canvas</div> and button? Cause that didn't work. By the way I did google it and the results weren't too helpful. I found a solution where someone used position:absolute. But in that's just ridiculous because isn't that just a fixed position that doesn't change with the size of the browser?

Comment: Perfect, thank you. Code and website looks a lot cleaner now.